# Запуск Genymotion

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

После установки и при запуске Genymotion выбрасывает ошибку:

> unable to load virtualbox engine

Насколько я понял, это проблема сети VirtualBox. Нашёл совет про удаление виртуального хоста в VirtualBox, но в моей ситуации это не помогло, так как список хостов пуст.

Существуют ли иные методы решения проблемы?

Пробовал установку и запуск от администратора. Не помогло.

ОС Windows 10.

Comment: Возможно аппаратная виртуализация не включена http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545704/Ошибка-при-старте-genimotion-windows-7-x64