# Ошибка при старте Genimotion windows 7 x64

Tags: java, android, android-studio, эмулятор

Запускаю Genimotion из под чистой windows 7 64 бита. При старте получаю ошибку

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.

В файле general-genymotion.log информация об ошибке следующая:

> июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] Unable to load translations. Falling back to english
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] "Local socket created at path : \.\pipe\907f397a1f5a71abaaa526042f58a1b0"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.2"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\genymotion.exe")
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/windows/x64/"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.7.2" ) available here: "http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.7.2/genymotion-2.7.2.exe"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion is up to date
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7ffafbff"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path from registry: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 8
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 4
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPU number is > 8 - Fix max number to 8
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 32730
>   июл 17 21:22:48 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
>   июл 17 21:22:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
>   июл 17 21:22:49 [Genymotion] [Warning] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" interface status (  QHostAddress( "169.254.143.99" )  )
>   июл 17 21:22:49 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
>   июл 17 21:22:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 0
>   июл 17 21:22:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" created with success
>   июл 17 21:22:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
>   июл 17 21:22:56 [Genymotion] [Error] [createHostOnlyInterface] Unable to retrieve interface
>   июл 17 21:22:56 [Genymotion] [Error] [createHostOnlyInterface] Output: "Name:            VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
>   GUID:            17eae86c-aa7c-4b43-ae41-44ac1da2c800
>   DHCP:            Disabled
>   IPAddress:       169.254.143.99
>   NetworkMask:     255.255.0.0
>   IPV6Address:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:f174:a44d:b8cf:8f63
>   IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64
>   HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
>   MediumType:      Ethernet
>   Status:          Up
>   VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

Полный список ошибок приведу по [ссылке](http://s92640jz.bget.ru/habra_example/123.txt)

Подскажите как подлечить?

Comment: Посмотрите вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951147/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-windows-10)

Comment: И да, установлен ли у Вас `VirtualBox`?

Comment: VirtualBox установлен

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox установлен, проблему решил путём включения в биосе технологии Intel VT-D. Спасибо за помощь.